# python Splinter browser.fill method freezes the browser

Tags: python, splinter

I am playing around with Splinter on yahoo register page. Something went wrong when I try to fill out the yahoo username.
Following is the code. I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with following code.

```
with Browser() as browser: 
# Visit URL
    url = "https://edit.yahoo.com/registration?.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.pd=ym_ver%253D0%2526c%253D%2526ivt%253D%2526sg%253D&new=1&.done=http%3A//mail.yahoo.com&.src=ym&.v=0&.u=3lt6ffl9q1g0m&partner=&.partner=&pkg=&stepid=&.p=&promo=&.last=&fsredirect=1&fs=uKhjpV.HafCCqUaFfpsAA6U3jii0wwSSblFjRz2HbaZq5sH_VJeVqejV5CUyegWCV3V2PxNx"
    browser.visit(url) 
    browser.fill("yahooid","Zara")
```

If I stop the program, the browser will be alive again. 
One of my guess is it is waiting for something such as the username suggestions, since it works fine with "first name" and "last name" fields.

I am using Windows 8,Eclipse,Splinter 0.6.0,Firefox 30.0

While playing around with Splinter, there is another method I can use to do the same thing.
Until this issue is addressed, people with same issue can use following concept.

```
with Browser() as browser: 
# Visit URL
    url = "https://edit.yahoo.com/registration?.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.pd=ym_ver%253D0%2526c%253D%2526ivt%253D%2526sg%253D&new=1&.done=http%3A//mail.yahoo.com&.src=ym&.v=0&.u=3lt6ffl9q1g0m&partner=&.partner=&pkg=&stepid=&.p=&promo=&.last=&fsredirect=1&fs=uKhjpV.HafCCqUaFfpsAA6U3jii0wwSSblFjRz2HbaZq5sH_VJeVqejV5CUyegWCV3V2PxNx"
    browser.visit(url) 
    #browser.fill("yahooid","Zara")
    browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('yahooid')[0].value='Zara'")
```

Comment: Which splinter and firefox versions are you using?

Comment: splinter I am using is version 0.6.0, and firefox is version 28.0

Comment: Does upgrading to the latest firefox (currently 30.0) help?

Comment: I just upgraded firefox to 30.0 and it doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the same tools on Mac - cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ye, it is wired. If I only fill it with a single character, it will do what it should be doing. But if I put more than 1 characters it will not. By the way I am using Windows 8. I will try to reinstall firefox and splinter later.